# Angular2 Query Params Subscription Fires Twice

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-routing

Trying to handle an OAuth login scenario where if the user lands on a page with `authorization_code` in the query string, we process the token and continue **or** if they land on the page without that, we check local storage for their existing token, make sure it's still valid and either redirect to login or continue, based on its validity.

The problem is that where we're checking for the existence of the `authorization_code` query string param, the subscription is firing twice. The first time it is empty, the second time it has the correct value in the dictionary.

**app.component.ts**

```
export class App implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _router: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('INIT');
        this._route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            console.log(params);
        });
    }
}
```

This code outputs:
[image: output]

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XgCauzZdTSqqokCdFWCi?p=preview) (you'll need to pop it out into a new window and add a query string `?test=test`).

**Questions**

1. Is there something I'm doing wrong to make it fire twice?
2. I can't just ignore the empty object with a conditional because that's the scenario where we need to validate the existing auth token -- is there another way of approaching this that isn't a complete hack?

Comment: An interesting twist... when no query string is supplied, the subscription only fires once.

Comment: I tested it as [https://embed.plnkr.co/XgCauzZdTSqqokCdFWCi/?test=test](https://embed.plnkr.co/XgCauzZdTSqqokCdFWCi/?test=test) and nothing unexpected happened !?

Comment: @A_Singh you test wrong url so you get only the first empty value

Comment: I have this issue when using location.go(), and then trying to get the query parameters when the user uses the browser to navigate back.

Comment: Put your subscription code on ngAfterViewInit method, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39861547/angular2-query-params-subscription-fires-twice/57354457#57354457

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Router observables (as another answer mentions) [are `BehaviorSubject` subjects](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.1/modules/%40angular/router/src/router_state.ts#L65-L70), they differ from regular RxJS `Subject` or Angular 2 `EventEmitter` in that they have the initial value pushed to the sequence (an empty object in the case of `queryParams`).

Generally the possibility of subscribing with initialization logic is desirable.

The initial value can be skipped with `skip` operator.

```
this._route.queryParams
.skip(1)
.subscribe(params => ...);
```

But more natural way to handle this is to filter out all irrelevant params (initial `params` falls into this category). Duplicate `authorization_code` values can also be filtered with `distinctUntilChanged` operator to avoid unnecessary calls to the backend.

```
this._route.queryParams
.filter(params => 'authorization_code' in params)
.map(params => params.authorization_code)
.distinctUntilChanged()
.subscribe(authCode => ...);
```

Notice that Angular 2 imports a limited amount of RxJS operators (at least `map` in the case of `@angular/router`). If full `rxjs/Rx` bundle isn't used, it may be necessary to import extra operators (`filter`, `distinctUntilChanged`) that are in use with `import 'rxjs/add/operator/<operator_name>'`.

Comment: +1 for getting to the root of and explaining the issue. But the answer doesn't fix the issue as the absence of authorization_code needs to send it on another code path.

Comment: The question isn't clear enough on how you expect to handle redirects. Any way, I believe that the first snippet covers that in the way that is most idiomatic to RxJS. BehaviorSubject causes extra value and skip(1) eliminates it.

Comment: In the first example, if there are no queryParams the first "empty" object will be skipped and the subscribe block will never be called.

Comment: Skip should now be placed inside of pipe: .pipe(skip(1)).subscribe

Answer (score 7):

You can wait until NavigationEnd event is done and then get the values or subscribe to changes:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('INIT');
        this.router.events
         .subscribe((event) => {
           if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {

             // Get a good value
             let initialParams = this.route.snapshot.queryParams; 
             console.log(initialParams);

             // or subscribe for more changes
             this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => { 
               console.log(params);
             });

           }
       }); 

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way to overcome this was subscribing router events, and processing query params only after the route is ticked to `navigated` state:

```
  public doSomethingWithQueryParams(): Observable<any> {
      let observer: Observer<any>;
      const observable = new Observable(obs => observer = obs);

      this.router.events.subscribe(evt => {
        // this is an injected Router instance
        if (this.router.navigated) {
          Observable.from(this.activatedRoute.queryParams)
            // some more processing here
            .subscribe(json => {
              observer.next(json);
              observer.complete();
            });
        }
      });
      return observable;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone is looking for a solution to this, I found a workaround that works pretty well. The solution I came up with involves only doing the subscription on the `NavigationEnd` event of the Router instance.

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .subscribe(e => {
        if (e.constructor.name === 'NavigationEnd' && this.router.navigated) {
          this.route.queryParams
            .subscribe(params => {
              // do something
            })
            .unsubscribe();
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Elegant and understandable solution. As suggest, you can replace the if statement by `.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd))` before subscribing.

Comment: `.unsubscribe()` works for my case. Since my query will get called again in parent component anyway. `.unsubscribe()` is an effective, simple and fast solution. To avoid params get subscribe twitce unexpectedly.

Comment: `e.constructor.name === 'NavigationEnd'` will fail with `optimization = true` (usually the case for production builds). You should use a filter and `instanceof NavigationEnd` like @BeardOverflow suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's by design.

`queryParams` is the **BehaviorSubject**

As you can see in the [docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/subject.md#behaviorsubject)

> One of the variants of Subjects is the BehaviorSubject, which has a
>   notion of "the current value". It stores the latest value emitted to
>   its consumers, and whenever a new Observer subscribes, it will
>   immediately receive the "current value" from the BehaviorSubject.

As workaround you can use `debounceTime` operator as follows:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';

this._route.queryParams
  .debounceTime(200)
  .subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params);
  });
```

Comment: This works most of the time, but don't like the possibility of exceeding the debounceTime timeout. Need to handle this query param regardless of which page they land on, and with varying load times this doesn't quite work.

Comment: This is not a good solution as it relies on arbitrary timing values that slow the app down, or break it completely if the timing isn't met.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Location` class to get initial url, `UrlSerializer` class to parse url, `UrlTree` to get query params.

Comment: While this doesn't solve the technical issue I was having with `Observable<Params>` it does solve for our specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

if you go to this link https://dev-hubs.github.io/ReactiveXHub/#/operators/conditional/skipUntil

1) *Copy Paste* this code in the code editor.

```
/* since queryParams is a BehaviorSubject */
var queryParams = new Rx.BehaviorSubject();//this will AUTOMATICALLY alert 'undefined'

var subscription = queryParams.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        alert(x);
    },
    function (err) {
        alert(err);
    },
    function () {
        alert('Completed');
    });
queryParams.onNext('yay');//this will cause to alert 'yay'
```

2) Hit **Run** Button

You will see that you will alerted twice, one directly on subscription and second bcz of the last line.

The current result is not wrong, thats the philosophy behind Rx 'operators make things happen' you can lookup this decision tree to see the operator you are looking for http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#tree
I usually use skip(1)

Answer (score -2):

Put your subscription code on ngAfterViewInit method,

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      debugger;
    });
}
```