# QueryParams/ParamMap Always Comes Back Empty

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get a parameter `serverId` from the URL using the following setup:

```
    constructor(private peopleService: PeopleService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
            console.log(params); //params is empty here
             //...
```

Here's my setup in app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, RouterModule.forRoot([])],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

I've also tried using `queryParams` instead of `paramMap`, any method I've seen results in an empty parameter list so I'm assuming there's something wrong with my setup.

Is there something else I need to do to set this up? I'm providing the parameter correctly in the url as `url?serverId=123`.

Comment: coul you make a stackblitz?

Comment: Not very easily, would I just be putting the entire app into it?

Comment: I mean if you are able to reproduce th e problem that would be nice. could you also tell us which version of angular and angular/router you are using

Answer (score 0):

If your routing Module is like this:

```
{
 path: 'url/:serverId ',
 component:MyComponent
}
```

so ,I guess that component is loaded before the actual routing applied.
Please Add { enableTracing: true } to the RouterModule to see what is happening behind the scene.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([], { enableTracing: true })
```

then you can subscribe queryParams :

```
// ...
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

@Component({ ... })
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  serverId: string;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams
      .filter(params => params.serverId)
      .subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params); // { serverId: "123" }

        this.serverId= params.serverId;
        console.log(this.serverId); // 123
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you just copy pasted [a whole post here ] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295469/why-queryparams-are-empty) please quote

Comment: where would I see the tracing?

Comment: @muttley91 every where you subscribe queryParams .

Comment: @muttley91 was it useful ?

Comment: No I don't understand how to see the result of the trace.

Comment: that's pretty much exactly what I have except for the filter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226763/discussion-between-arash-hatami-and-muttley91).

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had my `app-routing-module.ts` set up as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

which means that the imports in my `app.module.ts` should have read as follows:

```
imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, AppRoutingModule]
```