# Route query parameters is empty on first render in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router, query-string, angular-activatedroute, angular-router-params

I have a scenario in which I decide the actions based on the query parameters of the angular url.

For example, if the url is `localhost:4200/token=abc` I need to do some tasks and if the url is `localhost:4200` then I need to do something else. I have added this logic in the `ngOnInit()` of `app component`. The problem is, the query parameters are empty while rendering the component for the first time, and it takes a while before the params value is fed.

Code:

```js
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,private router:Router){}
    ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: any)=>{
    console.log("params 1:",params);
    if(Object.keys(params).length){ //If there are query parameters 
          console.log("If exectued",params);
         //do Something 
    }
    else{
        console.log("Else exectued",params);
        //do Something else
     }
    })
  }
```

The problem is params are empty initially and it goes to `else` condition. It again goes to `if` afterwards. The output is something like

```
params 1: {}
Else executed > {} 
If executed > {token:abc}
```

How to check if the route has been initialized properly with parameters and then proceed?

PS: I found a [similar thing in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61043260/8070068) but how to do this in Angular?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295469/why-queryparams-are-empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue and was able to have two different solutions for it. Posting the solution for people looking for it.

> The query parameters are initially empty or does not load the values first  because the components loads before the actual routings are
> applied.

### Solution 1

Wait for the navigation to end using `event` property [NavigationEnd](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd)

```js
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router:Router) { }
ngOnInit(): void {  
    this.router.events.subscribe(
      (event: RouterEvent) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: any)=>{
        if (Object.keys(params).length) { //Query params 
          doSomething();
        }
        else
          doSomethingElse();
       })
      }
      })
}
```

### Solution 2

Adding a delay, say .10s to ActivatedRoute to capture the route query parameters. Although adding delays is not considered good as per coding norms, but this can be beneficial in some scenarios where a certain delay is already required to trigger a popup or some logic on page load.

```js
 ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: any)=>{
        if (Object.keys(params).length) { //Query params 
          doSomething();
        }
        else
          doSomethingElse();
      })
    }, 10);//A dealy of 10ms is provided here
}
```

In  both of the solutions, `if` block or `doSomething()` function is triggered first.

PS: Refer to [David Rosey's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295469/why-queryparams-are-empty) and the  [blog by Ben Nadel](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3362-adding-delay10-to-activatedroute-helps-prevent-unwanted-router-behaviors-in-angular-4-4-6.htm) to get into more details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try **ActivatedRoute** just with 'params' (instead queryParams)? ...I don't really know if it has a different behaviour:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: any)=>{
    console.log("params 1:",params);
    if(Object.keys(params).length){ //If there are query parameters 
          console.log("If exectued",params);
         //do Something 
    }
    else{
        console.log("Else exectued",params);
        //do Something else
     }
    })
  }
```