# constructor runs twice only with parameter

Tags: angular

I am trying to pull a URL parameter value in the constructor, and for some reason, the constructor is always executed twice.

Now I have found the many articles about boot strapping the parent and child together in the module, but I only have a single page app.  This is also different because the double execution only happens if there are any parameters on the URL.  It works correctly, if none are provided.

any ideas?

thanks

```
constructor(
   public translate: TranslateService,
   public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
) {
     this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
     this.os = params['os'];
     console.log(this.os)
});
```

}

Comment: The constructor runs twice seems unlikely. The subscription fires multiple times seems more likely.

Comment: Is the value of 'os' different in the subsequent logs?

Comment: @silvermind.  The first one will be undefined, the second will have the proper value

Comment: You are correct, is the subscription firing many times.  But Why?  and why would it be empty the first time and then show all the values the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add if params has value like this

```
constructor(
   public translate: TranslateService,
   public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
) {
     this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
     if(params != null && params != undefined) {
     this.os = params['os'];
     console.log(this.os) }
});
}
```

Hope useful

Comment: I starting digging around after @Silvermind noted that it wasn't the constructor, and i found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39861547/angular2-query-params-subscription-fires-twice

Comment: the above link give a lot of data, and it seems the end answer is to user this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(params => {  ,which skips the first empty set

Comment: @Limey if data exist in first time then skip(1) can throw exception ?!

Comment: according to the like, it will always show twice, its built that way, so shouldn't be an issue.