# router.params.subscribe runs twice in succession

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I am subscribing to my route params in angular but it keeps returning two values (the previous url and the present one), which messes up my code. I tried using the `take` operator to return only one instance of the params, but it returns the previous url instead.

Update: I edited the code to use the `skip` operator and the `take` operator and this time it does return the right params, but it still runs more than once which causes the array duplication and if I try to route to the same route again (which my situation requires), it doesn't get any params because I am skipping the first value

```
this.route.params.pipe(skip(1), take(1)).subscribe((params) => {
      console.log(params);
      if (params) {
        this.subscription = this.chatService.oneChannel(params['id']).subscribe((channel) => {
          this.channel = channel!;
          for (let i = 0; i < this.channel?.members!.length; i++) {
            this.chatService.getUserData(this.channel?.members![i]).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(result => {
              this.members.push(result!);
            })
          }
        })
      }
    })
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I think you want to `skip(1)` instead.

Comment: Detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39940166/5058682)

Comment: Let me input the full code

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Let me try it out

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm skip(1) actually skips the previous url and returns the current one, but it doesn't stop the subscription from running more than once, so my array still gets populated needlessly

Comment: @KhumoMogorosi I have edited the code with updates

Comment: @AmitKumar Please look at my updated question. I made use of the skip operator

Comment: you can also use skip(1) and take(1) after

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I just noticed that the skip operator prevents the user from re-routing to the same route. In my case it's a sidebar that contains an array of groups. When the user clicks on a group, it displays its members and also routes the rest of the page, in order to display the messages. So if the user clicks on the same group, it doesn't run

Comment: You’re using nested subscriptions, that will get you in trouble always in the end..

Comment: @MikeOne what would be the alternative?

Comment: Use proper rxjs operators like switchMap

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to use a combination of **switchMap** and **mergeMap/concatMap** to achieve what you are trying to. *Subscribe within a subscribe is not a good thing to do*. Instead use the flattening operators that RxJS gives your nested subscriptions. There should only be a *"single"* subscription at the end of your observables' chain.

As a pseudocode, the above code should be similar to this

```js
  this.activatedRoute.params
            .pipe(
                switchMap(params => {
                    return this.chatService.oneChannel(params['id']);
                })
            )
            .pipe(
                concatMap(channel => {
                    this.channel = channel!;
                    for (let i = 0; i < this.channel?.members!.length; i++) {
                        return this.chatService
                            .getUserData(this.channel?.members![i])
                            .pipe(take(1))
                            .subscribe(result => {
                                this.members.push(result!);
                            });
                    }
                })
            )
            .subscribe(response => {
                console.log(response);
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. This will be a good example for avoiding nested subscriptions. I already figured out the answer though. I just simply created a local variable for the array pushing and equated by global array to it after the for loop. So no matter how many times my route.params subscribes I do not get a duplicated array

Comment: @Kotai, no problem, if the answer helps please mark it as the answer :)