# ActivatedRoute.queryParams fired again after updating queryParams

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, query-string

In my angular component I make an API call, passing some hash string that I read from the current query params. With my API result I do also get a new hash, which I set as the new hash query param. Thus, the next API call will be with my new hash. The stripped down (mock) code looks like this:

```ts
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, filter, first, mergeMap, of } from 'rxjs';

export class ResourceTableComponent{
  constructor(
    private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
    private readonly router: Router
  ) {}

  protected hash = firstValueFrom(
    this.route.queryParams.pipe(
      filter((params) => 'hash' in params),
      mergeMap((params) => this.fetch(params['hash'])),
      mergeMap((hash) =>
        this.setQueryParams({ hash }).then(() => hash)
      )
    )
  );

  protected fetch(hash: string): Observable<string> {
    console.log('fetch', hash);
    return of(Date.now().toString());
  }

  private setQueryParams(queryParams: Params): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.router.navigate([], {
      queryParams,
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
    });
  }
}
```

The problem now is, that now `fetch` is called 4 times, this is what's getting logged:

```
fetch 1691227799752
fetch 1691228130070
fetch 1691228130110
fetch 1691228130131
```

What I want is, that `fetch` is called once, the hash query param is updated from `fetch` result, and the next call to `fetch` will only happen when reloading the page or when I trigger the call elsewhere.

This can of course be achieved using `first()`:

```ts
this.route.queryParams.pipe(
  filter((params) => 'hash' in params),
  first(),                                              // <- rxjs first()
  mergeMap((params) => this.fetch(params['hash'])),
  mergeMap((hash) =>
    this.setQueryParams({ hash }).then(() => hash)
  )
)
```

**But I do wonder why this is even necessary. I'm aware of `queryParams` being an `BehaviorSubject`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39861547/angular2-query-params-subscription-fires-twice#39940166) for example. But I still don't really understand when emissions of `queryParams` actually end, why for example am I getting *4* calls?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically `this.setQueryParams` makes an emission to `this.route.queryParams`, and, considering that in most cases rxjs streams are synchronious, all the synchronious logic is executed immidiately (which causes this.setQueryParams execution again).

why 4? it is hard to say and it really depends on the exact code, api latency and async route change execution time. It stops when the whole stream emits first value, which with the help of `firstValueFrom` helper gets consumed and the whole stream gets an unsubscription - dies = no more calls.

Comment: Thanks alot. So piping `first()` is the right way of dealing with this?

Comment: yes, unless you are using route reuse strategies it should work

Comment: Ok, what I ended up now with is instead of `first()` I simply pulled `setQueryParams()` out like so: `firstValueFrom(...).then(this.setQueryParams)`. So when the query params are updated, `queryParams` has already completed (because of the use of `firstValueFrom`, as you pointed out).